# SonarQube - Using wildcards to ignore all xml files

Tags: sonarqube

I have confused on SonarQube's wildcards usage. Say I want to ignore all xml files. Should I just put `*.xml` in the Global Source File Exclusions? But will it ignore xml files in different layers, for instance `/foo/bar/file.xml` and `/foo/bar/folder/folder2/xml`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your `sonar-project.properties`, you have two ways to ignore files:

- `sonar.exclusions=the/full/path/*.xml` will ignore all `.xml` files in `path`.
- `sonar.exclusions=**/*.xml` will ignore all `.xml` files in the folder and sub-folders where you are.

Here are the different wildcards:

```
*    zero or more characters
**   zero or more directories
?    a single character
```

You can find more information on [Sonar Documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus)

Comment: Thanks. So **/*.xml will basically ignore all xml files in all directories and sub directories.

Comment: You welcome ! :)  To ignore all `.xml` files in current directory and sub-directories, you should use something like `**/*.xml`