# Exclude Javascript file from sonar scan

Tags: javascript, java, sonarqube

I want to exclude a Javascript file from sonar scan.

Is there any sonar code I can use in the js file to perform this?

In a Java file, I could use @SuppressWarnings("squid: S0016").
Can I simulate this in the js file?

I have seen posts to set in properties etc. But, don't have one so I was wondering if that can be performed in the file and if so how can I perform the same?

Comment: to exclude a js (java script) file from sonar scan -> https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=exclude+java+script+file+from+sonar+scan&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SonarQube - Using wildcards to ignore all xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017527/sonarqube-using-wildcards-to-ignore-all-xml-files)

Comment: for js function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320062/javascript-equivalent-of-supresswarning //nosonar tag and activate it...